# How to pass custom values to Autocomplete input type on selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Here is my code:

```
    $(function(){
      // User autocomplete
          $('#search').autocomplete({
              source: function(req,res) {
                  $.ajax({
                      url: "/auto",
                      dataType: "json",
                      type: "GET",
                      data: {
                          term: req.term
                      },
                      success: function(data) {
                          res($.map(data, function(item) {

                              return {
                                  "label" : item.name,
                                  "value" : item.name,
                                  "id"    : item.id,
                              };
                          }));
                      },
                      error: function(xhr) {
                          alert(xhr.status + ' : ' + xhr.statusText);
                      }
                  });
              },
              select: function(event, ui) {

                  alert(ui.item.id);

              }
          });

    });
```

When I alert **ui.item.value** it works fine; but when I use **ui.item.id** it doesn't work; I get undefined error. 
What's the right way to alert id here?

Comment: If you run `console.log(ui.item)` it will show you all of the properties of item. The problem might be that item.id isn't being set in the first place

Comment: @yamboy1 It is not being passed to item. What should I modify in the code to pass it?

Comment: What's not being passed to item?

Comment: @yamboy1 id is not being passed to item in select function.

Comment: Have a look at @Nirav Joshi 's answer

Comment: I believe it is because you are not allowing the asynchronous assigning of ui.item.id to be completed before your `select: function(event, ui) {...};` is called. Try adding some type of promise... https://www.promisejs.org/

Comment: @PhilipCorneliusGlover I didn't realise it was async. I probably should have though

Answer (score 1):

Damn! I made a silly mistake. It was **item._id** in success function instead of id.

Answer (score 0):

It's a just try i think the `id` name is ambiguous in result. the select function confuses in `item.id` and in `id`

So try with this hope it will helps you.

```
return {
          "label" : item.name,
          "value" : item.name,
          "idx"   : item.id,
       };


select: function(event, ui) {
              alert(ui.item.idx);
        }
```